# Partylist in Microsoft Dynamics Crm 4.0

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

Is it possible to create an attribute of type Partylist in Microsoft Dynamics Crm 4.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PartyList type is basically a system control to display a n:n relationship on emails.  Right now, we are not allowed to create new attributes of type PartyList.

Answer (score -1):

```
<attribute PhysicalName="to">
  <Type>partylist</Type>
  <ValidForCreateApi>1</ValidForCreateApi>
  <ValidForUpdateApi>1</ValidForUpdateApi>
  <ValidForReadApi>1</ValidForReadApi>
  <IsLogical>1</IsLogical>
  <AttributeTypeId>00000000-0000-0000-00aa-110000000039</AttributeTypeId>
  <DisplayMask>ValidForForm|ValidForGrid|RequiredForForm</DisplayMask>
  <Descriptions>
    <Description description="Sending Mails to the specified Users." languagecode="1033" />
  </Descriptions>
  <ImeMode>auto</ImeMode>
  <RequiredLevel>none</RequiredLevel>
  <Format />
  <LookupClass>SystemUsers</LookupClass>
  <LookupStyle>multi</LookupStyle>
  <LookupTypes>
    <LookupType id="f93fb506-2341-db11-898a-0007e9e17ebd">8</LookupType>
  </LookupTypes>
  <displaynames>
    <displayname description="Users" languagecode="1033" />
  </displaynames>
</attribute>
```

Just add code to any entity where you want Party list attribute.
Tested working Fine.

Comment: This is unsupported and may prevent Microsoft support from helping you out if you ever have an issue.